# What property does this equation calculate?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, geodesy

It's pretty difficult to Google for the meaning of a formula.

This is the equation, it has to do with ellipses and GIS coordinates.

$$\nu =\frac{ a} {\sqrt{(1 - (e^2 \cdot \sin(\varphi))^2)}}$$

$a$ is an ellipsoid axis.

$\varphi$ is geodetic coord latitude in radians.

$e^2$ is eccentricity squared.

I see it all over the code I'm porting and would like to separate it out but I can't figure out what to call the function!

Edit: On page 38 of [this PDF](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/gps/docs/A_Guide_to_Coordinate_Systems_in_Great_Britain.pdf) the equation and its context is described.

Comment: I believe it describes a band of some kind. $a<\phi<b$

Comment: $3.14159 n-0.443255<\phi<3.14159 n+0.443255$

Comment: where $n \in Z$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_form_relative_to_center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You link has broken in the last six years, but something like that expression now appears in Annex B (page 47) of https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/docs/support/guide-coordinate-systems-great-britain.pdf which has $$\nu =\frac{ a} {\sqrt{1 - e^2  \sin^2(\varphi) }}$$

If the world was spherical with radius $r$ then a point with latitude $\varphi$ and longitude $\lambda$ would have $(X,Y,Z)$ co-ordinates

- $X=r \cos(\varphi) \cos(\lambda)$
- $Y=r \cos(\varphi) \sin(\lambda)$
- $Z=r \sin(\varphi)$

but with an ellipsoid, the coordinates of a point on the ellipsoid (ignoring height above the ellipsoid) would be

- $X=\nu \cos(\varphi) \cos(\lambda)$
- $Y=\nu \cos(\varphi) \sin(\lambda)$
- $Z=(1-e^2)\nu \sin(\varphi)$

with $\nu$ defined as above.  Note that $\nu$ varies with latitude $\varphi$

So $\nu$ is close to the idea of a radius: because of the $(1-e^2)$ term, it is not quite the distance from the centre of the ellipsoid to a point of latitude $\varphi$, but it is not far away

Personally I would just call it `nu` or perhaps something like `ellipsoid_nu`

Comment: Thanks. What made you revisit this question after 6 years!?

Comment: @James - I was looking at something else with the `geodesy` tag and came across it